# Cocos2d game Timer

Tags: objective-c, timer, count, cocos2d-iphone

I want to add a timer to my game.  I have a GameManager singleton.

```
-(void) startTimerWithDuration:(float) duration
{
    [self schedule:@selector(timeUp) interval: duration];
}
-(void) timerUp
{
    [self unschedule:_cmd];
    [self lose];
}
-(void) lose
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene: [GameOverScene node]];
}
```

Then in my GameScene init, I have

```
[self addChild:[GameManager node]];
```

Then I have:

```
[[GameManager sharedManager] startTimerWithDuration:60.0f];
```

I get this error in console:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[CCTimer initWithTarget:selector:interval:
```

And this is the cctimer

```
#if COCOS2D_DEBUG
    NSMethodSignature *sig = [t methodSignatureForSelector:s];
    NSAssert(sig !=0 , @"Signature not found for selector - does it have the following form? -(void) name: (ccTime) dt");
#endif
```

I don't know why. Are there some common approach to counting the time? Since it is a common usage I guess.

Comment: what method do you want to schedule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
-(void) timerUp
{
    [self unschedule:_cmd];
    [self lose];
}
```

should be

```
-(void) timerUp:(ccTime)delta
{
    [self unschedule:_cmd];
    [self lose];
}
```